# How to set date-format with condition in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

I want to set date-format if column type date.

my code as the following :

```
<div ng-repeat="col in gridColumnDefs">
    <div pi-grid-column sort-enable="true" sort-direction="0"
         filter-enable="true" column-width="185px"
         display-name="{{col.DisplayName}}"
         column-type="{{col.ColumnType.toLowerCase()"
         property-name="{{col.Name}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I know column type, code something like this :

```
<div pi-grid-column sort-enable="true" column-width="100px"
     sort-direction="0" display-name="Date 1" property-name="Date1"
     column-type="date" date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" filter-enable="true">
</div>
```

I use ng-repeat and gridColumnDef is my columns array.

```
display-name="{{col.DisplayName}}" : 'Date1'
 column-type="{{col.ColumnType.toLowerCase()" : "date"
property-name="{{col.Name}} : "date1"
```

`if col.ColumnType = "date" ? date-format: dd/MM/yyyy` . I dont know how do in html page inside div tag

date-format should set if columnType = date, if columnType != date not set date-format.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Angular Expression to interpolate the logic needed on the custom attribute date-format:

```
<div pi-grid-column sort-enable="true" column-width="100px"
    sort-direction="0" display-name="Date 1" property-name="Date1"
    column-type="date" date-format="{{ col.ColumnType === 'date' ? 'date' : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}" filter-enable="true">
</div>
```

I suggest to move this logic to controller and call one method to retrieve the correct value:

```
$scope.defineDateFormat = function _defineDateFormat(column) {
    return column.ColumnType === 'date' ? 'date' : 'dd/MM/yyyy';
}
```

Then:

```
<div pi-grid-column sort-enable="true" column-width="100px"
    sort-direction="0" display-name="Date 1" property-name="Date1"
    column-type="date" date-format="{{ defineDateFormat(col) }}" filter-enable="true">
</div>
```